# In Turkish locale [Enum].GetName does not return correct name. Why?

Tags: vb.net, enums

In **Turkish** Locale, the following seems to be a problem:

```
 Public Enum enFonts
    TOKEN_Line_Number = 2
  End Enum

  Dim StyleName As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(enFontsUpper), fnt).ToUpper
```

StyleName is set to "TOKEN_LxNE_NUMBER" where x set to uppercase I with **dot on the top**. Why?

Here is a test code that demonstrates this behaviour:

Joginder

```
Module Module1
  Public Enum enFonts
    TOKEN_Plain_Text = 1
    TOKEN_Line_Number = 2
  End Enum

  Public Enum enFontsUpper
    TOKEN_PlaIn_Text = 1
    TOKEN_LIne_Number = 2
  End Enum

  Friend Styles As New Collection

  Sub Main()
    Dim STL As String = "TOKEN_LINE_NUMBER"
    Dim fnt As enFonts = enFonts.TOKEN_Line_Number

    'The following compare fails
    Call Compare(STL, enFonts.TOKEN_Line_Number)

    ' The following compare works because In changed i to uppercase I in LIne
    Call Compare2(STL, enFontsUpper.TOKEN_LIne_Number)

  End Sub

  Private Sub Compare(STL As String, fnt As enFonts)

    Dim StyleName As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(enFonts), fnt).ToUpper

    If StyleName.Equals(STL) Then
      Call MsgBox(String.Format("'{0}' is equal to '{1}'", STL, StyleName))
    Else
      Call MsgBox(String.Format("'{0}' is NOT equal to '{1}'", STL, StyleName))
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub Compare2(STL As String, fnt As enFontsUpper)
    Dim StyleName As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(enFontsUpper), fnt).ToUpper

    If StyleName.Equals(STL) Then
      Call MsgBox(String.Format("'{0}' is equal to '{1}'", STL, StyleName))
    Else
      Call MsgBox(String.Format("'{0}' is NOT equal to '{1}'", STL, StyleName))
    End If

  End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Tag with the programming language, please.

Comment: Pretty infamous, google "the Turkish I problem" for basic hits.  You'll have to decide what language you use to write your enum variables.  Looks roughly like CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to me, definitely not Turkish.  So tell ToUpper() about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have now discovered that the problem is with `ToUpper` in Turkish locale. `"i".ToUpper` returns capital I with dot on the top.  There seem to many solutions in Stackoverflow for this problem. Simple solution is to use `ToLower` instead of `ToUpper.